# how can I sort tcl associative array based on its keys?

Tags: arrays, sorting, tcl

I have an array named "test":

```
key -> value
a      4
f      5
c      3
b      0
d      9
```

And I want to sort the array as:

```
a 4
b 0
c 3
d 9
f 5
```

I tried using:

```
    set sorted_array [lsort [array names test]]
```

but this only returns me: a b c d f
how do i get the entire array with the values also (sorted according to the keys)?

I was able to get the sorted result. Now I tried storing it as a sorted array named "sorted_array" using the code given below :

```
foreach idx [lsort [array names test]] {
    append result "$idx $test($idx)" 
    set sorted_array($idx) $test($idx) 
}
```

Now when i print the array "sorted_array" using :

```
foreach index [array names sorted_array] {
puts "sorted_array($index): $sorted_array($index)"
}
```

But, I get the same array as "test", and not a sorted one.

Comment: The `parray` proc does this: in an interactive session, do `parray env` (to load the proc) then `info body parray`

Comment: Tcl arrays do not remember the "insertion order" (dictionaries do, but they are not available in your old version of Tcl). Also, it is an associative array, and an associative array has no inherent ordering (it's a set of key-value pairs). Sorting only makes sense at the time when you want to output the array,

Answer (score 3):

With `stride` option in `lsort`, we can get this done easily.

> -stride strideLength
>
> If this option is specified, the list is treated as consisting of groups of >strideLength elements and the groups are
>   sorted by either their first element or, if the -index option is used,
>   by the element within each group given by the first index passed to
>   -index (which is then ignored by -index). Elements always remain in the same position within their group. The list length must be an
>   integer multiple of strideLength, which in turn must be at least 2.

```
array set test {
    a      4
    f      5
    c      3
    b      0
    d      9
}
puts  [lsort -stride 2 [array get test]]
```

**Output:**

```
a 4 b 0 c 3 d 9 f 5
```

**Reference :** [lsort](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TclCmd/lsort.htm#M14)

**Update :**
If you have `Tcl` version less than 8.5, then you have to sort the array's indices and get the array values.

```
array set test {
    a      4
    f      5
    c      3
    b      0
    d      9
}

foreach idx [lsort [array names test]] {
    append result "$idx $test($idx) "
}
puts $result
```

which will give the same output as per my first approach.

**Update 2:**

```
# Here, I have given 'lsort', because of appending the to 
# list in a sorted manner. Else, it is not required.
# i.e. If you only intend to save the values into array, 
# then we don't need 'lsort' here.
foreach idx [lsort [array names test]] {
    append result "$idx $test($idx)" 
    set sorted_array($idx) $test($idx) 
}
# lsort is mandatory for the array indices, so that while
# printing the elements, it will be in sorted form.
foreach index [lsort [array names sorted_array]] {
    puts "sorted_array($index): $sorted_array($index)"
}
```

As Mr.Glenn Jackman, Instead of doing this way, you can also use `parray` to show the sorted array as output.

```
parray sorted_array
```

Comment: And we can output it with `foreach {key val} [lsort -stride ...] {puts "$key $value"}`

Comment: `lsort -stride` doesn't work for me. Is there another way to sort this?
`bad option "-stride": must be -ascii, -command, -decreasing, -dictionary, -increasing, -index, -indices, -integer, -nocase, -real, or -unique
    while executing
"lsort -stride 2 [array get test]" `

Comment: @surabhinayar : It seems you have Tcl version less than 8.5, which is why it is failing. I have updated my answer. Please check.

Comment: thanks for the updation, i am getting sorted results now. Now i am trying to make an array that is sorted, so instead of append, i did -
`foreach idx [lsort [array names test]] {
       set sorted_array($idx) $test($idx)
  }`
and when i print sorted_array, i do not get the desired result. i again getthe same array as test.

Comment: @surabhinayar :  Can you tell me in what way you have tried to print the array ? Can you update your code in your post ?

Comment: @surabhinayar : I have updated my answer. Please check.